# .htaccess ReWriteRule - Requested URL <rewritten filename> was not found on this server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've been testing this in WAMP and I can't get it to work.  I believe WAMP is set up properly due to the error message I'm receiving and it works no problem when I don't use the .htaccess file.

I have a filename that I'm using for testing called Feedback.php.  Instead of displaying as **`www.mysite.com/Feedback.php`**.  I'm trying to get it to just be **`www.mysite.com/Feedback`**.

.htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^Feedback.php/?$ Feedback [NC]
```

The error message that I receive is

> "Not Found
> The requested URL /Feedback was not found on this server."

Are there two files required for reWriteRule to work?

I'm also trying to get this to work for my index.php to just be www.mysite.com which may be a different monster.

What should my navbar links be?  Right now they are `<a href="Feedback.php">Feedback</a>` Should `href` perhaps be `href="Feedback"` once I get this working?

---

**EDIT:** I had the ReWriteRule variables backwards.  Instead of

```
RewriteRule ^Feedback.php/?$ Feedback [NC]
```

I should have

```
RewriteRule ^Feedback/$ /Feedback.php [NC,L]
```

The rewrite doesn't look to have taken place though as it still reads localhost/Feedback.php

Comment: You're doing it the other way around. Your rule should be `RewriteRule ^Feedback$ /Feedback.php [NC,L]`. This is always like `RewriteRule WHAT WHERE`

Comment: Thank you!  Didn't realize that.  My URL still reads http://localhost/Feedback.php though, so although it loaded, the rename doesn't look to have worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this to remove `.php` extension from your pages as well as omitting the `index` part to your website:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index
RewriteRule ^index$ http://yourwebsite.com/         [R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php                            [L]
```

Comment: @john stamos I've been using the code snippet in my answer and it always works for me

Comment: Thank you for this.  I believe what was wrong was that my href links were <a href="feedback.php"> instead of <a href="feedback">.  We are to reference the new name correct?

Comment: Certainly!! you need to exclude `.php` from your links `www.examplesite.com/examplepage`

Comment: **********! I'm a newb.  Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: You welcome, we're all newbies when learning new stuff, i'm glad it helped